# ListViewItem Border - Compact Framework

Tags: c#, listview, compact-framework, border, listviewitem

I have a `ListView` where I add as `Items` some `ListViewItem`s. The `View` property is set to `Details`. When the `ListView` is displayed the `ListViewItem`s haven't any border (top and bottom line that separates one item from another).

How can I do to add a border to all my items?

An example:

[image]

Comment: Hey, I think someone borrowed an image of mine! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For whatever reason, Gridlines aren't supported by the CF control, though the underlying native ListView does.  P/Invoke to the rescue.

```
private const uint LVM_FIRST = 0x1000;
private const uint LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE = LVM_FIRST + 54;
private const uint LVM_GETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE = LVM_FIRST + 55;
private const uint LVS_EX_GRIDLINES = 0x00000001;

[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
private static extern uint SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint msg, uint wparam, uint lparam);

public void EnableGridlines(ListView listView)
{
    var style = SendMessage(
            listView.Handle,
            LVM_GETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE,
            0,
            0);

    style |= LVS_EX_GRIDLINES;

    var style = SendMessage(
            listView.Handle,
            LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE,
            0,
            style);    
}
```

Comment: It works, I can see a light blue border. How can I change the color and the line thickness?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to change color or thickness of the border (though I've also never looked for a way).

Comment: If one day you will know the answer please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

ListView doesn't support GridLines in compact framework. You can use DataGridView